# url masking in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am using a .htaccess file. I want to rewrite my domain as follows:

`www.example.com` to `www.example.com/en/`

I have tried like

```
  RewriteRule ^http://example.com/en/ index.php
```

My /en/ folder does not exist, and I don't want to create it. I just want, if a user hits www.example.com then it should shows www.example.com/en/ and loads the index page from the root.

But its not giving me the desired result.

Is this possible?

Comment: A couple of possibilities: 1) is mod_rewrite enabled? 2) are there other rules that might be conflicting with this one (ie. show us the whole `.htaccess` file. 3) turn on logging for `mod_rewrite` ([docs here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog)) and see what it's doing. Finally, you say "it's not giving me the desire[d] result" - what is it giving you? Share that information because it might help diagnose the problem.

Comment: my all the other url rewriting defined in the same htaccess is working fine. this is the only issue remaining.

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite rule you've shown matches `http://example.com/en/` and changes it to `index.php` - it doesn't do anything with `http://www.example.com`, so it won't give you the rewrite you're looking for.

I'm no expert on rewrite rules, but it seems to me you need a new rule before the one you've listed:

```
RewriteRule ^http://www.example.com http://www.example.com/en/
```

The order of these rules is going to be important - you'll need to hit this rule first, then the one you've listed above.

Also, there may be interactions with your other rewrite rules or conditions - look out for that if it doesn't work.

I got this by [reading the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Check there for more info on how these things work.